# Problema al ejecutar una consulta sql python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Buenas estoy haciendo un programa en python que saque una lista de una base de datos sqlite y despues genera dos numeros random, he puesto que el tamaño de los numero como máximo sea la longitud de lo que devuelva la cadena, hasta aquí todo bien, el problema viene cuando la consulta tarda un poco mas los numeros random no se generan ya que no hay longitud para generarlos.

Como puedo hacer para solucionarlo? En javascript usaba promesas pero en python no se como hacerlo.

Este es el código que tengo para sacar la lista de usuarios:

```py
lista_usuarios = []

for i in cur.execute('SELECT usuario FROM users;'):
lista_usuarios += i

con.close()
```

Y este es el codigo que tengo para generar los numeros random:

```py
lon = len(lista_usuarios)

num1 = random.randrange(lon)
print(num1)
num2 = random.randrange(lon)
print(num2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes probar con el siguiente codigo:

```
lista_usuarios = cur.execute('SELECT usuario FROM users;')
```

De esta forma obtendrias todos los registros de la tabla, si en realidad no necesitas obtener el nombre de los usuarios prueba con:

```
cantidad_usuario = cur.execute('SELECT count(usuario) FROM users;')
```